# Как реализовать разворачивающийся item listview?

Tags: android, listview

Как реализовать разворачивающийся `item listview`?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. В адаптере на нужный элемент вешайте слушатель нажатий.
2. В нём назначайте высоту по содержимому/конкретную высоту в `dp`/`px`. этому элементу